# Splitting the Java builder to avoid writing same code multiple times

Tags: java, builder

I have a piece of code which looks like below:

```
Problem hashProblem;
String indexName;
if(condition.getOwner() != null) {
    indexName = sourceLocation ;
    hashProblem = new Problem().builder()
        .locationID(condition.getLocationID())
        .sourceLocation(condition.getSourceLocation())
        .build();
}
else {
    indexName = currentLocation;
    hashProblem = new Problem().builder()
        .locationID(condition.getLocationID())
        .currentLocation(criteria.getcurrentLocation())
        .build();
}
```

Is there a way to write this code in a more elegant way? While building the hashProblem object setting the locationID is always required. I am unable to think of a way to split the builder so that I could write .locationID only once. I am using Lombok(https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder.html) for builder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  A builder is an object just like any other.  Instead of creating the builder and calling `build()` in one big statement, you can save a reference to the builder, do something to it conditionally, and then call `build()`.

```
Problem hashProblem;
String indexName;
Builder builder = new Problem().builder().locationID(condition.getLocationID());
if(condition.getOwner() != null) {
    indexName = sourceLocation ;
    builder.sourceLocation(condition.getSourceLocation())
}
else {
    indexName = currentLocation;
    builder.currentLocation(criteria.getcurrentLocation())
}
hashProblem = builder.build();
```

By the way, `new Problem().builder()` looks a bit strange in terms of naming conventions.  Typically you would see `new Problem.Builder()`, where `Builder` is a nested class of `Problem`, or `Problem.builder()` (no `new`) where `builder()` is a static method that returns a `Problem.Builder`.

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using Lombok for builder. If I dont use new Problem(), I get an error method call expected

Comment: If I use Lombok's Builder: Builder b = new Problem().builder().locationID(condition.getLocationID()); , I get an error Incompatible types

Comment: Instead of `Builder b`, make `b` whatever type `Problem().builder()` returns.  I just called it `Builder` because that's the usual name for a builder class.